# Firebase deploy specific directory inside functions directory

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

In Firebase I know that deploying functions and specific functions is possible:

`firebase deploy --only functions`

But is it possible to deploy a specific directory (e.g. views) in the functions directory?

`Root > Functions > Views`

I'm asking this because sometimes I only have updates in a specific `handlebar` template that is inside my `Views` directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although my question focuses on deploying a specific directory inside the functions directory. My main reason for asking this question is because sometimes I only have updates in a specific handlebar template that is inside a specific directory and I find it time consuming to wait for the functions to deploy because of having so many functions to update.

So if you have changes in the directory, like in my case a `handlebar` template, and you do not need for the functions to be updated in the deployment process, then just deploy one specific function to make the deployment process quicker.

Because this step happens:

`functions: functions folder uploaded successfully`

before this step:

`functions: updating function . . .`

So just call:

`firebase deploy --only functions:functionName`

By doing this, you upload the functions directory and only need to wait for one function to be updated.